# How to remove the first element with map()

Tags: react-native

I'm newbie in react and I would like to remove the first element in a card array object

```
      <View style={styles.block}>
         {
          this.props.cards.map((card: ICard) => (
            <CardListItem key={card.id} card={card} />
          ))
        }
      </View>
```

I try with `this.props.cards.slice(1).map` but it's not working, if someone can help me, it could be very nice

Comment: this.props.cards.delete(1).map

Comment: Thanks for your answers but it's still not working, I forgot to tell it's an array object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this way to

Check current index if `index != 0` then only return component

```
<View style={styles.block}>
  {
    this.props.cards.map((card: ICard, index) => {
      if(index != 0) return <CardListItem key={card.id} card={card} />;
    })
  }
</View>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `filter` instead.

```js
const cards = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const cards_filtered = cards.filter((e,i) => i!=0);
console.log(cards);
console.log(cards_filtered);
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you are not using splice properly try the below snipet

```js
const cards = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
console.log(cards);
cards.splice(1,1);
console.log(cards);
```

all you need to do is `this.props.cards.slice(1,1)`